# Why does my custom allocator preform proportional to malloc?

Tags: c++, memory-management

I am benchmarking a custom memory allocator and found something interesting. The code I am testing is like this

```
int main(){
//default malloc
    auto start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto x = malloc(32);
    *(int*)x = 50;
    auto end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start); 
    cout << duration.count() << endl;

//custom allocator
    Allocator a;
    start = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto p = a.allocate(32);
    *(int*)p = 50;
    end = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end - start); 
    cout << duration.count() << endl;
return 0;
}
```

I get results like

```
$./a.out
3751
719
$./a.out
3419
458
$./a.out
2355
541
$./a.out
921
217
$./a.out
2453
521
```

The results seem proportional when one runs fast the other is fast too. Why is that? In my mind, they should be independent.

Comment: It's impossible to tell without knowing how your custom allocator works.

Comment: @J.Schultke it does not use malloc

Comment: Profiling the first time your code runs is a very bad idea. There might be tons of hidden costs that are incurred just once. Loading libraries, paging stuff in, initialization, etc... Run a loop of at least a thousand and then plot all times. Check if the correlation still holds.

Comment: Are you running an optimized build?

Comment: How do you know your custom allocator doesn't use `malloc` -- even if indirectly?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i compile with g++ -03

Comment: `malloc` lurks at the bottom of virtually every dynamic allocation.

Comment: I am using some allocations on the stack, but I don't think they should use malloc

Comment: An automatic allocation won't use the heap, unless the automatic allocation runs off and grabs data from the freestore while initializing. But... returning a pointer to an automatic allocation is almost always a bad, bad idea. Show the allocator code, please. The answers you seek are likely hidden within.